# Can't install PyQt5 on python 3 with spyder ide

Tags: python, interface, pyqt5

So I'm trying to install the PyQt package so I just did this on my Anaconda Prompt:

```
C:\Users\USER>pip install PyQt5
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.0-5.15.0-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-none-win_amd64.whl (64.5 MB)
Collecting PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.8
  Using cached PyQt5_sip-12.8.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (62 kB)
ERROR: spyder 4.1.4 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
ERROR: spyder 4.1.4 has requirement pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3", but you'll have pyqt5 5.15.0 which is incompatible.
```

So I tried a different version with:

```
pip install --upgrade --user pyqt5==5.12
```

And then this happened:

```
Collecting pyqt5==5.12
  Downloading PyQt5-5.12-5.12.1_a-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-none-win_amd64.whl (49.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 49.4 MB 43 kB/s
Collecting PyQt5_sip<4.20,>=4.19.14
  Downloading PyQt5_sip-4.19.19-cp37-none-win_amd64.whl (52 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 52 kB 3.8 MB/s
ERROR: spyder 4.1.4 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To install PyQt5 without errors try this. First install pyqtwebengine version 5.12 and then install pyqt5 version 5.12, using the following commands:

```bash
pip install --upgrade --user pyqtwebengine==5.12
pip install --upgrade --user pyqt5==5.12
```

By this, I have successfully installed pyqt5